# Highcharts - Slow Stochastic Indicator Error

Tags: highcharts

I have Highcharts chart rendered on yAxis[0] and whenever the user selects an indicator like Aroon Oscillator, MACD etc. it is added as a new yAxis in the rendering container. Example:

[image]

The above snapshot is with the Aroon Oscillator. All good.

When i select Slow Stochastic though i get the following:

[image]

First of all both SS$K and SS$D have the same value as you can see in the tooltip which is clearly wrong and both lines have the same color for a reason when they should not because:

[image]

I tried to log the p.series.yData[p.point.index] (the currently hovered point yData value) in my console and for my surprise I get the following:

[image]

It returns an array (but why) of 2 values, and both plots access the first value, instead of SS%D accessing the second value. This is a Slow Stochastic problem from Highcharts since the Aroon Oscillator which has the same philosophy of many plots on the same yAxis, still works fine as you can see in the first picture (where the lines have the correct color and correct values assigned).

Lastly as you can see with another indicators MACD (which has the same issue as mentioned before with Slow Stochastic) - and VPT which works as intended, when i go full range, those have a gap at start. Why is that happening?

[image]

Has anyone come across a similar indicator problem from Highcharts and if so, could anyone give me his/her lights on how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance, Christopher.

P.S. Those are my tooltip options for highcharts:

```
  tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        let finalDate = '';
        let tooltipString = '';
        $.each(this.points, function(i, p) {
          // console.log(p.series.name, p.series.yData[p.point.index]);
          //Starting date
          let dateTo = new Date(p.x),
            month = '' + (dateTo.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + dateTo.getDate(),
            year = dateTo.getFullYear();

          if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
          if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

          let intradayTime = '';
          if (p.point.isIntradayData) {
            let hours = dateTo.getHours();
            let minutes = ('0' + dateTo.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
            intradayTime += ' ' + hours + ':' + minutes;
          }

          dateTo = [day, month, year].join('.');

          //If we wanna display previous date too:
          let dateFrom = '';
          if (p.point.previousDate) {
            dateFrom = new Date(p.point.previousDate);
            month = '' + (dateFrom.getMonth() + 1);
            day = '' + dateFrom.getDate();
            year = dateFrom.getFullYear();

            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
            dateFrom = [day, month, year].join('.');
            dateFrom += ' - ';
          }

          finalDate = dateFrom + dateTo + intradayTime;
          if (p.series.userOptions.compare == 'percent') {
            tooltipString +=
              '<br>' +
              `<span style="color:${p.color}; font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">` +
              p.series.name +
              ': </span>' +
              '<span style="font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">' +
              ' ' +
              p.point.percentageDifference +
              `%(${p.y})`;
            ('</span>');
          } else if (
            p.series.type == 'candlestick' ||
            p.series.type == 'ohlc'
          ) {
            tooltipString +=
              '<br>' +
              `<span style="color:${p.color}; font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">` +
              p.series.name +
              ': </span>' +
              '<br>' +
              '<span style="font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">' +
              'Open: ' +
              p.point.open +
              '<br>' +
              '<span style="font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">' +
              'High: ' +
              p.point.high +
              '<br>' +
              '<span style="font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">' +
              'Low: ' +
              p.point.low +
              '<br>' +
              '<span style="font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">' +
              'Close: ' +
              p.point.close +
              '</span> <br>';
          } else {
            let pointValueFormatted = p.y.toFixed(2);
            tooltipString +=
              '<br>' +
              `<span style="color:${p.color}; font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">` +
              p.series.name +
              ': </span>' +
              '<span style="font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">' +
              ' ' +
              pointValueFormatted +
              '</span>';
          }
        });
        return (
          '<span style=" font-size:10px; font-family:\'Arial\'">' +
          finalDate +
          '</span>' +
          tooltipString
        );
      },
      borderColor: '#7fb7f0',
      shared: true,
    },
```

***INDICATORS LOGIC***

It's impossible to reproduce it in jsfiddle due to the size, the complexity and for security reasons due to policies. So a user can select indicators from a tabmenu like:

[image]

and they way the indicators are sorted:

```
    //Sorting indicators.
sortIndicators() {
  console.log(`Function Call: sortIndicators()`);
  this.cleanIndicators(); // Just clearing the chart yaxises and the indicators array list to iterate over indicators again.
  let counter = 0;
  //For every indicator
  for (let indicator of this.indicators) {
    //If it is chart indicator we render it on yAxis[0] with our prices
    if (toolsManager.isChartIndicator(indicator)) {
      //some indicators have multiple arrays of data instead of one saved in an array called arrayOfObj
      if (indicator.arrayOfObj) {
        for (let arg of indicator.arrayOfObj) {
          this.highchartOptions.series.push(arg);
        }
      } else {
        this.highchartOptions.series.push(indicator);
      }
    } else {
      //If it not chart indicator
      this.highchartOptions.chart.height +=
        2 * this.yAxisMargin + this.yAxisHeight;

      let topCalculation =
        456 + (counter + 1) * this.yAxisMargin + counter * this.yAxisHeight;

      //yAxis to add
      let addedAxis = {
        title: {
          enabled: false,
        },
        opposite: true,
        min: null,
        height: this.yAxisHeight,
        top: topCalculation + this.yAxisMargin,
        showLastLabel: false,
        labels: {
          enabled: true,
          x: -30,
          y: 0,
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            color: '#999999',
          },
        },
      };

      this.highchartOptions.yAxis.push(addedAxis);
      if (indicator.arrayOfObj) {
        //some indicators have multiple arrays of data instead of one saved in an array called arrayOfObj
        for (let arg of indicator.arrayOfObj) {
          //for every array of that arrayOfObj
          arg.yAxis = counter + 1;
          this.highchartOptions.series.push(arg); //push it to series
        }
      } else {
        indicator.yAxis = counter + 1;
        if (indicator.id === 'volume') {
          indicator.data = this.volumeSeries;
        }
        this.highchartOptions.series.push(indicator);
      }
      counter++;
    }
  }
},
```

the part where the magic happens is here:

```
    if (indicator.arrayOfObj) {
    //some indicators have multiple arrays of data instead of one saved in an array called arrayOfObj
    for (let arg of indicator.arrayOfObj) {
      //for every array of that arrayOfObj
      arg.yAxis = counter + 1;
      this.highchartOptions.series.push(arg); //push it to series
    }
  } else {
    indicator.yAxis = counter + 1;
    if (indicator.id === 'volume') {
      indicator.data = this.volumeSeries;
    }
```

the reason it is implemented like this is because when an indicator is selected an object is returned from the server which may have one of the two following structures:

data structure 1:
[image]

data structure 2:
[image]

And after sorting out what type of structure I am dealing with, I am pushing it into the series to display. counter variable is just used for the y-axis's. Arron Oscillator and Slow Stochastic both fulfill the first part of the conditional, because both return an object which contains and arrayOfObj (for the line colors etc as you can see in the photo uploaded).

Comment: Please reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor that allows community to debug it.

Comment: Indicators like MACD and others are called `lagging indicators`. What does it mean? It means that to calculate some point in the time, you have to have a few previous points. The amount of points usually is described by the `period` parameter (usually it equals 14, 20, 25). This means that the first few points will be missing, that is how the indicator's algorithm works.

Comment: When it comes to your tooltip issue could you please share a simple how you are adding the indicators that we can debug it?

Comment: Good morning, thanks for the replies. Would it be possible to set the parameter period to 0 for example, so in that case there wont be missing values at start, or thats not how lagging indicators are supposed to work?

I will update the topic with more info regarding how i am adding the indicators.

Comment: @KarolKołodziej  - JSfiddle is not an option, but i did the best i could to provide you with information ! Is this ok?

Comment: Are the options from each indicators' source code exposed to us somehow? For example file StochasticIndicator.js has some options like the default tooltip, and the smoothedLIne color (it can be found in node_modules->highcharts->es-modules->stock->indicators->stochasticindicator.js) but i rather not touch the source, just have it exposed somehow ?

Comment: Theoretically, it's posible to set the indicators period to lover value however it will represent something else. More information about lagging indicators: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/l/laggingindicator.asp

Comment: Each option mention in the `specificIdicator.js` file is described in the API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.slowstochastic.params

Comment: In your case, I suspect that the sorting mechanism might cause issues with displaying properly the series. Could you please check if it works without that? I'm also not sure how `cleanIndicators`method works that's why I suspect that part.

Comment: This was a life saviour. After taking a look at the files in node modules to see the structure of the tooltip of each indicator being used by highcharts api, i did manage to pass plotoptions for each of the indicator while loading the indicators from the backend. Thank you Karol!!!!